# will mysql guarantee binary log (bin log) write Table_map event/Write_rows event/Xid event atomically?

Tags: mysql, innodb

try to use bin log to read incremental data but insert/update/delete events only record table id while table id is record in Table_map event before these modified events.
so is insert/update/delete events and Table_map event are atomically written into binary log so that certain modify events' table name can be told by very close previous Table_map event?

if not, how to get table name for certain insert/update/delete events with table id?

Comment: Have you considered reading code of other tools that do this, like [Debezium](https://debezium.io) or [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html)?

Answer (score 0):

@BillKarwin 
after I read another project:maxwell(https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell) the answer is yes, mysql transactionnly write insert/update/delete events with begin(event type = Query) and COMMIT(event type = Xid)surrounding them.

if read master binlog directly, there could be one corner case AFAIK, the server crashed during write each transaction, then there will be unclosed events. so I just need to cover this case.
so basically my solution is below:

at the very beginning, I fetch the complete data with below actions:

```
flush tables tableA, tableB, tableC WITH READ LOCK; 
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;
show master status;
//record binlog filename and position
UNLOCK TABLES;
//read complete data
commit;
```

with above action, not only get complete data, but also record the related binlog position.

each time after this, I start to read binlog from the position last time record and get the data I interested with caution to take care of the corner case I mentioned above since the unclosed events may be rolled back by mysql server.

after read binlog, record the position of currently read for next iteration.

@BillKarwin, thanks for u help